# MS Access Dmax: I have 13 rows of different Pets and need to find Last Visit for each?

Tags: ms-access, vba

The problem: Create a `LastVisitDate` field/column using the `DMax` function based on `Pet`.

The only tables I am allowed to use are `tbl_Customer` and `tbl_Pets`. I am suppose to add a field and use the Expression builder using `Dmax` accessing/referencing `tbl_Visits` that has `PetID` (text field). I have 13 distinct records to find their last visit date for each in the query. This is what I have:

```
LastVisit: DMax("VisitDate","tbl_Visits","[PetID]= " & 'PetID')
```

But, it returns a single date( which is the latest date in the Visits table) for all the records, which is incorrect.

I also tried this, but it returns nothing:

```
LastVisit: DMax("VisitDate","tbl_Visits","[PetID]= '*'")
```

I know the error has to do with how I have set up my "Criteria." Any Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

(I have an alternate way of adding Visits table, VisitDate and then do Totals and Group By "Max" which gets me the result, but I am not suppose to be adding `tbl_visits` to my query.)

Comment: Do you need the date of the last entered record? If so then I think you need to use the `dlast()` function?

Comment: Well, yes. But the requirement is asking to use "DMax" function to retrieve the last visit!

Comment: "This is what I have: LastVisit: DMax("VisitDate","tbl_Visits","[PetID]= " & 'PetID') But, it returns a single date( which is the latest date in the Visits table) for all the records, which is incorrect." what is incorrect about this, is the date incorrect or the fact it is only returning a single date which you feel is incorrect?